# move file to ~/.trash, with unique filename

Tags: bash

I have the following alias in my ~/.bashrc

```
alias del="mv -t ~/.trash"
```

This moves a file or directory to the ~/.trash folder. However, if I do the following:

```
del test.txt
touch test.txt
del test.txt
```

The second `del` call overwrites the already existing file test.txt in ~/.trash, hence I lose my backup. This is of course unwanted behaviour. I'm looking for a way to adapt my alias, so that a file which is moved to ~/.trash is appended with the date and time of the moment that is was moved there, hence resulting in an unique filename. Does somebody have an idea of how to do this? I'm looking for an easy way to adapt the alias, not an extensive bash script.

Comment: for a quicker fix there is --backup option on move to make a backup of each existing destination file

Comment: You rely on your trash folder as a *backup mechanism* ??? Get yourself a cheap external hard disk and get Time Machine set up, before you lose something important.

Comment: @Paul, You are making incorrect conclusions, which are not based on the content of the question.

Comment: You said "hence I loose my backup" - apart from the typo, is that not correct ?

Comment: `del` is used instead of `rm`, the ~/.trash folder works as backup to recover files in case something is deleted which I shouldn't have. It has nothing to do with the regular backups I make of my files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a function. Functions are also recommended over aliases.

```
function del {
    local F
    for F; do
        mv -- "$F" ~/.trash/"$F-$(exec date '+%F-%T')"
    done
}
```

Place it in `.bashrc` and make sure `.bash_profile` *sources* `.bashrc` as well.

See the [date manual](http://praxis.edoceo.com/man/1/date) (`man date`) for other formats you can use.

Comment: Sorry I was to quick with my comment, i didn't source the .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mktemp --tmpdir`.

```
$ alias del="mv -t \$(mktemp -d --tmpdir=$(echo ~)/.trash)"
$ touch test
$ del test
$ find ~/.trash
/home/username/.trash
/home/username/.trash/tmp.hJQTaEAx6Q
/home/username/.trash/tmp.hJQTaEAx6Q/test
```

Answer (score -1):

I think i'd make a mini script instead of an alias

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)

for file; do
    mv "${file}" "${HOME}/.trash/${DATE}_${file}"
done
```

you can create the files in the trash with the file name **before** the date (but you'll loose the extension - although that's fixable too).
Just don't use the script multiple times for the same file names on the same **second** :) if you insist you can add nanoseconds to the date stamp.